# Devise losing session when I'm using ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

### Environment

- Ruby **2.6**
- Rails **6.0**
- Devise **4.7.2**
- Database **Postgres**

### Current behavior

Hi,
I'm using a custom Middleware to connect to correct database based on subdmain

```rb
module Vtenancy
  class WebTenancyMiddleware
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      Rails.logger.info("env #{env['SERVER_NAME']}")

      if (Vtenancy::Tenant.current = Vtenancy::Tenant.tenant_from_env(env))
          Vtenancy::Tenant.current.establish_connection
          @app.call(env)
       else
        [404, {}, []]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
module Vtenancy
  class Tenant < Vtenancy::ApplicationRecord
     def self.current
      if Rails.env.test?
        @current
      else
        RequestStore.store[:tenant]
      end
    end

    def self.current=(tenant)
      if Rails.env.test?
        @current = tenant
      else
        RequestStore.store[:tenant] = tenant
      end
    end
   

    def establish_connection
      Vtenancy::Tenant.current = self
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(name.to_sym)
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.enable_query_cache!
    end

  end
end
```

I add it before Warden::Manager

```rb
  config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Vtenancy::WebTenancyMiddleware
```

But, when I access a page with a lot of requests, some fails with 401. Totally random

I'm using cookie session on Rails.

---

## Edit 1

I changed the code a little bit because I read from rails issues (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37158) that connect to with database will be removed.

But anyway, using establish_connection have the same problem.

---

## Edit 2

I set puma threads to one and now it's working.
It's not the solution I need because It make my application note mult thread

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a red herring and that the "lost sessions" might actually be a separate cookie related issue? I can't see any logical reason why they would have anything to with each other.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for you response.

Cookie was my first concern, but I look on code and Chrome Dev tool and apparently the cookie is send right. And as I said, it's totally random.

My guess is that the problem is that devise are loosing the correct database for some reason, but i was not able to simulate it.

Comment: Postgres,
Another information (I will edit to add it on body).

Apparently, transform application in one thread per process (I'm using puma) make all works